# Inconsistent import statements required between PyPI and local dev

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, pypi, file-structure

I have a python package "fb" with the following file structure:

```
packageFolder
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── fb
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── foo.py
    └── fizz.py
```

__init__.py contains the following code:

```
from fb.foo import bar
from fb.fizz import buzz
```

The issue is that foo.py also needs to import buzz from fizz.py

For the PyPI install to work, foo.py needs to contain the line:

```
from fb.fizz import buzz
```

But for things to run locally for development, foo.py needs to instead contain:

```
from fizz import buzz
```

Reversing the import statements leads to a module import error in both cases.

What is the resolution to this issue?

Comment: How are you doing the local development — specifically, how have you installed your package locally?  Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using Python3. I have not installed my package locally, so local development runs the .py files directly and there is no danger of conflict. I only installed my package in a virtual environment to test that it works.

Comment: When you run things locally, the full path e.g. `from fb.fizz import buzz` should work, when you run everything from `packageFolder` -- or if `packageFolder` is in `sys.path` (check the PYTHONPATH environment variable)

Comment: @ELinda when I run "python fb/foo.py" from packageFolder with the import statement "from fb.fizz import buzz" I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fb'". Is this expected?

Comment: Ok I've made some progress using "from fb.fizz import buzz" in foo.py under the following conditions: If I run "python -m fb.foo" from packageFolder it works although it gives a confusing warning message. Also if instead of running foo.py directly, I create a file example.py in packageFolder with "from fb import bar" and run it from packageFolder using "python example.py" then it works also. Still I find this very confusing and it isn't clear what the best practice is.

Comment: this is a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time